# Is there a way to find the endpoint of a string array list?

Tags: android, arrays

Ok I have an sqlite database that is collecting data from the user- this is information is then sent to a string array and displayed on screen with the following code-

Heres the array and the int var

```
List<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();

int currentPos = 0;
```

Heres the next button code

```
 nextBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            currentPos ++;
            if (currentPos > 30) currentPos = 0;

            textView.setText(array.get(currentPos ));


        }
    });
```

and the previous button code

```
 prevBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            currentPos --;
            if (currentPos < 0) currentPos = 30;

            textView.setText(array.get(currentPos ));
        }
    });


}
```

Here's how this code works the two button allow the user to go back and forth in the array by changing the int using an increment while changing the current outputted text- this means you can go from 0 to 30 without a crash or vice versa.

this works fine when you have a set number amount of data in the array but it obviously crashes in this case when its impossible to hard code the amount of data that the user is imputing to sqlite and then the array.

The question is-is there a way around this i.e some code you could replace 30 with that would point to the end of the array?

Comment: array.size(); instead of number u can pass size of array.

Comment: Consider using better style practises. Those 1 liner if statements make me upset :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

arraylist.size() returns the size of the array or in your case array.size() will return the size of the array.

Comment: or in your case array.size() will return the size of the array.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are almost there:
your array has a method wich returns it own [size](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#size()):

```
List<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
int currentPos = 0;
...
currentPos = array.size();
nextBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            currentPos ++;
            if (currentPos > 30) currentPos = 0;

            textView.setText(array.get(currentPos ))
        }
    });
```